# How can I create a "sliding pages" effect in KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to have different pages slide in and out of the Viewport with KnockoutJS.

My page doesn't currently use jQuery, so I'd like to avoid it.

It should use CSS transitions.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with a binding, but first we need a helper function for our buttons.  It returns a click handler that sets an observable to a specific value.  It can be used like `data-bind="click: page.set(1)`.

```
ko.observable.fn.set = function(value) {
  var obs = this;
  return function(){ obs(value); }
}
```

Now our HTML will have a binding in the page container (`.pages`) telling us what page to be on.  Each page has a simple class which we use in to describe them.

```
<div class="pages" data-bind="page: page">
  <div class="page text-center">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
    <button class="btn" data-bind="click: page.set(1)">Go to Page 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Our CSS is a little strange.  We need to make `.pages` much larger than the body, and hide the horizontal scroll bars.  Note that we can divide 10,000 by our `.pages` width to get our `.page` width -- this is always true.  We also have a simple transition for sliding between pages.

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; }

.pages { 
  width: 10000%; height: 100%; position: relative; 
  transition: left .5s ease-in-out;
}

.page { width: 1%; height: 100%;  float: left;}
```

Finally, our binding handler sees what page it is, and determines the correct size.  Note that page 0 is the first.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.page = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var position = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

    console.log(position);
    element.style.left = position * -100 + "%";
  }
}

ko.applyBindings({page: ko.observable(0)});
```

Now we can bind our page observable.

```
ko.applyBindings({page: ko.observable(0)});
```

### and a [demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/xADcr) to wrap it all up